# Identify last effektive status in past

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to identify the last state for a variable regarding a specific month. For example

```
Variable        Date        Operation   State
    A           01Jan2019   1           10
    A           10Jan2019   3           20
    A           31Jan2019   4           50
    A           05Feb2019   7           60
    A           22Feb2019   8           70
    B           06Jan2019   2           10
    B           07Jan2019   3           20
    B           07Feb2019   6           60
    B           15Mar2019   9           80
```

The result should like

```
Variable    Month       Year    Last_State_Until_End_of_Month
    A           1       2019    50
    A           2       2019    70
    A           3       2019    70
    B           1       2019    20
    B           2       2019    60
    B           3       2019    80
```

Please note that for the variable A in March the last state is the same as for February. (No change was made during March). I don't know if it helps, but there is an operation ID the is increasing for each change of a state independent of the choise of variable.

Comment: Adding column headers to your sample data and output would be helpful

Comment: Columns where just not displayed. I changed it now

Comment: attending the explanation the result seems wrong. it should be 2 record for A. right?

Comment: No. Even if there was no change in the state, the last state should be displayed. Also when the last change was three month in the past.

Comment: Use a date column instead of strings. Use a Calendar table to easily get the year and month.  Once you do this you can use eg `LAST_VALUE(State) OVER (partition by year,month,variable roder by date)`

Comment: `Also when the last change was three month in the past` you can still use `LAST_VALUE`, perhaps `LAST_VALUE(State) OVER( ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos the follwoing query works:

```
declare @table_test TABLE (variable_name nvarchar(255), date_var date, op_id int, state int)
insert into @table_test Values 
    ('A',           '01Jan2019',    1           ,10),
    ('A',           '10Jan2019',    3           ,20),
    ('A',           '31Jan2019',    4           ,50),
    ('A',           '05Feb2019',    7           ,60),
    ('A',           '22Feb2019',    8           ,70),
    ('B',           '06Jan2019',    2           ,10),
    ('B',           '07Jan2019',    3           ,20),
    ('B',           '07Feb2019',    6           ,60),
    ('B',           '15Mar2019',    9           ,80)

select 
    year(date_var) as year
    ,month(date_var) as month
    ,variable_name,
    ,Last_value(State) OVER (partition by year(date_var),month(date_var),variable_name order by date_var ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as last_value
from @table_test
Order by variable_name, year(date_var),month(date_var)
```

This query returns:

```
year    month   variable_name   last_value
2019    1       A               50
2019    1       A               50
2019    1       A               50
2019    2       A               70
2019    2       A               70
2019    1       B               20
2019    1       B               20
2019    2       B               60
2019    3       B               80
```